# What does TF2 mean by "obtained by activating a retail version of Team Fortress 2"?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I want to get the Proof of Purchase, but i didn't buy the game on steam. I got an item for the Mann Co Store. I bought the orange box on XBOX 360 though. Is there a way I can get the Proof of Purchase?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the Proof of Purchase, you need to activate a PC retail version of the game, receive the game as a gift, or had TF2 before it went free to play. Unfortunately, your Xbox version won't count. By "activate", I'm referring to adding the CD-Key to your Steam account's library, which can be done by clicking "Add Game" in the bottom left corner of the Library tab:

[image]

From the [TF2 Wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Proof_of_Purchase)

> This hat is given to players who purchased Team Fortress 2 before the
>   Über Update on June 23, 2011, those who receive a gift of the
>   game, and those who activate a retail copy of the game.

Comment: And this is why the description of the Proof of Purchase says "From another era".

Comment: Keep in mind that gifting is a sort of quasi-flux way of getting it. Nobody is really sure if giving the Orange Box (which does still contain TF2) awards the hat judging from the responses I've gotten when I tried to ask.

Comment: @XKeeper Yes, if you purchase or unwrap the orange box, you get it.

Comment: I second that. I got the Orange Box as a Christmas gift from Steam last year, and activating it on PC automatically gave me TF2 premium and the hat.